# How to integrate an indicator function/constraint into the cost function of a linear program?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, mathematical-modeling

I have a mathematical model $P$ for which I optimize two cost functions say $F_1$ and $F_2$ subject to a set of constraints $C1$–$C10$.

In $F_2$, I want it to be included only when its expression violates a certain quantity. In fact, $F_2$ involves the product of two decision variables to be specific and its quantity should be multiplied by a penalty parameter say $\sigma$ only when it is greater than another quantity say $\alpha_i^{k,l}$.

$$F_2=\sigma \sum_{\mathcal{R}_i \in \mathcal{R}}\sum_{p^j_{(s^j, d^j)} \in \mathcal{P}} \sum_{(v^i_k, v^i_l) \in \mathcal{L}^i} x^{i, k}_{s^j}\times  x^{i, l}_{d^j} d^j_{(s^j, d^j)}.$$

$x$ is a binary decision variable, $d$ is a constant.

How do I model this and what should be the constraints I need to add into the set of existing constraints?

Comment: @RobPratt, the const function F_2 is now explicitly defined.

Comment: @RobPratt, x is a binary decision variable and d is a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will simplify the notation to illustrate the idea.  You want to minimize $$\sigma \max\left(\sum_{i,j} d_{ij} x_i x_j - \alpha, 0\right).$$
Introduce binary decision variable $y_{ij}$ to represent the product $x_i x_j$, and introduce nonnegative decision variable $z$ to represent the $\max$.  Now minimize $\sigma z$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
y_{ij} &\ge x_i + x_j - 1 \\
z &\ge \sum_{i,j} d_{ij} y_{ij} - \alpha
\end{align}

Comment: I will implement it and let you know if it worked. Thanks !

Comment: it did not actually work as expected. Is there something I need to consider as well ?

Comment: @LyLa What unexpected behavior did you see?

Comment: I am solving a relaxed version of the problem where I introduced the McCormick envelope for the product of the x^{i, k}_{s^j} by x^{i, l}_{d^j}. So, I ended up in a relaxed version that I round off but the cost function value (F1+F2) is lesser in the rounded solution than in the optimal one with your suggestion.

Comment: One possible source of discrepancy is that my suggestion penalizes only the part above $\alpha$ rather than the whole sum if it is at least $\alpha$, but that would tend to yield a smaller cost for my suggestion (the opposite of what you are seeing).  Are you sure that the rounded solution satisfies all the constraints?

Comment: I apologize for my previous comment which was not complete. It was a draft that I just removed.

Comment: @LyLa No problem.  Is there still an unresolved issue?

Comment: so far so good. Thank you so much!